# How can I get my overhand throw to properly turn over?

Tags: technique, disc-golf

I've been playing disc golf for several years and have experimented with an overhand (or tomahawk) shot for several years. However, the shot has always been inconsistent for me. It always gets the required height, but rarely achieves the distance I want on it. I know that there is a way to get it to turn over (so that the disc is flying upside down) and I occasionally achieve this, but I cannot do it consistently.

What is the technique for achieving this shot? Are certain discs better at achieving the turnover than others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8) video does an excellent job covering all aspects of overhand throws. From disc types, grips, usage and proper technique. Give it a look. I feel something like this is more easily explained with a good video tutorial.

### Video breakdown:

- [0:48](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=48) to 1:44, when to use overhand throws, and intended use.
- [1:45](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=105) to 2:00, best disc types for this throw.
- [2:06](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=126) to 4:05, pro #1 gives his tips on this throw. Pay good attention around 3:16 as I feel that was his greatest tip.
- [4:50](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=105), Tomahawk grip. (*I prefer the tomahawk over other overhand techniques, just my opinion. It's most intuitive and I feel I am very consistent with it*).
- [5:30](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=105), tomahawk throw technique.
- [~7:30](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ZQbxrr1v8&feature=player_detailpage&t=105), good explanations on arm height/angle, and the impact that has on the throw.

---

PS - [Mark Ellis'](http://www.discraft.com/team_ellis.html) YouTube series is if not *the best*, one of the best out there for all players, from beginner to expert. He's not got his own channel from the looks of it, but does numerous videos on [Discraft's YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/sportdisc).

Comment: @edmastermind29, explaining technique through the internet is so hard! Thankfully some awesome people maintain nice video series if you can find the good ones (there's 99:1 bad:good videos) ;) Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If its a new disc you may want to try bending it down towards the concave side. This can help the disc catch the air more and this will cause it to turn over.

Comment: I would advise against doing this. Sure, it might have an immediate -- and apparently positive affect -- on your throw, but in the long run you shouldn't do this to your disc.